# What exactly is the unit "GB-month" in AWS terminology?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, amazon-ebs, cost-management

Amazon EBS volumes are billed by the gigabyte-month (GB-month). With Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS), you pay only for what you provision. Volume storage for all EBS volume types is charged by the amount of GB you provision per month until you release the storage.

There is so much confusion in these statements, and I wonder how exactly EBS is billed and what exactly is meant by the unit **"GB-Month"**? I could see this unit is also associated with Amazon Aurora storage pricing.

*Links:-*

https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/

https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/pricing/

Comment: See [How are charges for Amazon EBS volumes calculated on my bill?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ebs-volume-charges/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `GB-Month` is 1GB of storage for 1 month.

- 100GB stored for 1 month = `100 GB-Months`
- 100GB stored for half a month = `50 GB-Months`

It's similar to the electricity concept of Kilowatt-Hours (1kWh = 1kW for 1 hour).

Comment: Kilowatt-hours example made it simple for me. Thanks.

When I first saw the unit GB-Month, I intuitevely thought it is like how many GBs per month. In other words as a division (no. of GBs / no. of months). But it is actually a multiplication (no. of GBs X no. of months). So we will get 1 GB-Month unit when we have 31-GB volume for 24 hours or 1-GB volume for 744 hours.